# How to handle different toolbars for different pages in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have to build 3 different pages and each page has a different toolbar.
I know that in app.vue the head section is rendered and the components should be the body so it would make sense to only have the toolbar in the app.vue section but the problem starts when I have 3 different toolbars when I call the 3 components.

Whats the correct way to do this? Should I have the toolbars in the components themselves even though its going to be rendered in the main section, or should I somehow, dynamically load the different toolbars on app.vue as I load the components?

this is a "representation" of I want to achieve.

- Page1.vue -> toolbar 1
- Page2.vue -> toolbar 2
- Page3.vue -> toolbar 3

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar task and what i did:

Make component-wrapper `<MyToolBar />` and in it use:

`<component :is='computedComponent'></component>`

In this component u should just import yours toolbars.

If u use a vue-router, u can use hooks to listen page route.
Or u can use props.

well, i don't know is it the right solution, but it worked in my case

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially make use of slots if there isn't any major differences between the toolbars. Read more about them [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Single-Slot). Hope this helps :)